# Replace all values before last non-zero in a column with 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes with same index and shape, say A and B. My goal is to calculate sum of each row in df_B, but if for any rows below the last non-zero value in df_A, these corresponding rows won't be counted in the sum in df_B. This is an example to show what I am doing:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,1,0,1,0], 'col2': [1,0,0,0,0]})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2,2,2,2,2], 'col2': [2,2,2,2,2]})

OR:

df_A:
col1|col2
1.  |1.  
1.  |0
0.  |0
1.  |0
0.  |0

df_B:
col1|col2
2.  |2.  
2.  |2
2.  |2
2.  |2
2.  |2
```

The output I want to get look like this:

```
df_B:
col1|col2
2.  |2.  
2.  |0
2.  |0
2.  |0
0.  |0
```

For each column in df_A, starting from the last non-zero value, values after this position in df_B will be 0.

Here is what I have tried and am stuck:

1. get the index position of the last non-zero value in each column, so ([3,1]) for the 2 col in df_A.

```
row_ix = df_A.shape[0]-df_A.ne(0).values[::-1].argmax(0)-1
```

2. for each column, set values before the row_ix position to 0 (this is essentially opposite of my solution, but I can reverse this to get my answer)

```
for i in row_ix:
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col].values[:row_ix[i]] = 0
```

Is this a correct approach, or is there a better way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
   def zero_index(df, column_name):
       indexer = df.index[df[column_name].eq(0)]
        # checks if the values are consecutive
        if np.any(np.diff(indexer) > 1):
            return indexer[-1]
        return indexer[0]


df_B.loc[zero_index(df_A, "col1") :, "col1"] = 0
df_B.loc[zero_index(df_A, "col2") :, "col2"] = 0

df_B


   col1 col2
0   2   2
1   2   0
2   2   0
3   2   0
4   0   0
```

Comment: Yes, this works great. Thank you! I was stuck on it for like an hour.